# Problemas com JSON no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

Olá

Estou com problemas com o `JSON` quando subo ele pro servidor..

Exemplo de uns dos meus código que usam `JSON`:

```
        $("input[name=people]").keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val() != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('/StockController/searchPeople')?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {name_people: $(this).val()},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#loadPeople').html("");
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(obj.length>0){
                            try{
                                var items=[];   
                                $.each(obj, function(i,val){                                            
                                    items.push($("<option  id="+ val.id_people +">"+ val.name +"</option>"));
                                }); 
                                $('#loadPeople').append.apply($('#loadPeople'), items);
                            }catch(e) {     
                                alert('Ocorreu algum erro ao carregar os Fornecedores!');
                            }       
                        }else{
                            $('#loadPeople').html($('<span/>').text("Nenhum Fornecedor encontrado!"));      
                        }       
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert("Ocorreu algum erro ao carregar os Fornecedores");
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#loadPeople').html(" ");
            }
        });
```

No servidor local ele roda tranquilo, mas quando subo pra um online o codigo para de funcionar, e retorna o seguinte erro no console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: você tem como postar o que sai no seu console.log() para o JSON que deseja manipular?

Comment: [{"id_product":"142","name_product":"Carregador de Celular Gen\u00e9rico","unit_price":"10.00"},{"id_product":"143","name_product":"Arroz Itatibaia","unit_price":"4.00"},{"id_product":"145","name_product":"Feij\u00e3o","unit_price":"10.99"},{"id_product":"146","name_product":"pao","unit_price":"12.00"}]

Comment: Este console.log() é do servidor ou do localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Tente trocar de:

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('/StockController/searchPeople')?>",
```

para:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('StockController/searchPeople')?>",
```

Se não funcionar poste o método searchPeople();

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu servidor pode ser uma restrição de acesso à saída JSON.
No php, você pode fazer isso para liberar a requisição:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Embora a forma mais adequada e segura de fazer isso seja, passando somente domínios que possuem permissão válida para a requisição:

```
$request = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if (in_array($request, array('siteA.com.br', 'siteB.com.br'))) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $request");
}
```